# Customized contact us page for logged in user

Tags: magento2, contact-us, contact-form

I wish to add a contact us page customized for the logged in user in magento2 website. It should be like it's activated when a person is logged in and it should not ask for name or email , it should be populated with the name from account only.  Only text field to ask a question should be active.  I tried putting a block with a call to the contact us page, but it won't work as I need it to work. How should I approach this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your theme directory, create directory `Magento_Contact` with subdirectory `templates`. In `templates` create the file `form.phtml` with this contents:

```
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Write Us') ?></span></legend><br />
        <div class="field note no-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.') ?></div>
        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input <?php echo empty($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ? '' : 'disabled' ?> name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('name') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input <?php echo empty($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ? '' : 'disabled' ?> name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment required">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This will add some custom logic to the form that disables the email and name inputs if the customer is logged in.

Comment: Hi, I did what you described here. But I am just getting a line and nothing else . The line says,  "Write Us

Jot us a note and weâ€™ll get back to you as quickly as possible.
Name".

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmO6Xk8N1CMfgaRTBaB6E9ON1sCnkA

Comment: Try flushing the cache.

Comment: I did that. But its showing same

Comment: You could try deleting contents of pub/static and var/view_preprocessed folders. What version are you using? The above code works in 2.1 but I'm not sure about older versions.

Comment: I am using  version 2.0.6